# Reference for estimation gaussian of the heat kernel 

Tags: reference-request, heat-equation, pr.probability

Let $(M,g^{TM})$ a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$ and $\Delta$ the Laplace–Beltrami operator. I would like to find a reference (analytic or probabilistic) for the following classic result.

> If $p_t(x,y)$ is the kernel of the semigroup $e^{t\Delta}$, then there exist $C,c>0$, such that
>   $$p_{t}(x,y)\leq \frac{C}{t^{n/2}}e^{-cd(x,y)^2/t}.$$

Comment: I don't have a copy so I don't know if it's in there, but one place I'd look is "Aspects of Sobolev-Type Inequalities" by Saloff-Coste.

Comment: Do you want the inequality to hold for every $0 < t$? That won't necessarily be the case for large $t$ without further hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probabilistic proof is given in the book: "Stochastic Analysis on Manifolds" by E. Hsu.
See Theorem 5.3.4, which also gives the lower bound.

Comment: It's worth noting that this proof is for *compact* Riemannian manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this can be found in Davies, *Heat kernels and spectral theory*.  I'll check when I get to my office in an hour or so.

Comment: You seem to live on a longitude with very long hours!

Answer (score 1):

You may also be interested in the following paper of Grigoryan, [Gaussian upper bounds for the heat kernel on arbitrary manifolds](http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~grigor/super.pdf), which establishes the desired Gaussian bounds whenever one can show that there exists $C>0$ such that for all $x\in M$ and $t>0$, $p_t(x,x) \leq Ct^{-n/2}$.  The latter estimate may be obtained via a Sobolev inequality or a Nash inequality or through other means (and I'm sure it's discussed in the Davies and Saloff-Coste books already mentioned).  This paper also establishes Gaussian upper bounds even when the function appearing in the 'on-diagonal bound' is not of the form $t^{-n/2}$, or if one only has control of $p_t(x,x)$ at two points $x_1$ and $x_2$.